# Passing parameters into Microsoft Azure QnA Bot

Tags: .net, azure, azure-qna-maker

I want a QnA bot that returns a specific variable based on what site I am on. (my link {enviormentVar}/somepath.doc)

E.G. If I have the bot a site https://mySitetest.com/home# I want the QnA to return, in a response, mySitetest to {enviormentVar} and it will be mySitetest

If I am on https://mySiteLive.com/home# I want the {enviormentVar} to be set as mySiteLive.

Is there anything I can do with the QnA bot to make this happen or does it have to be on the .net side?
If its the .net side, what way would be the best way to approach it if the best way to do this is on the .net side?

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions about what you've written above - you have a QnA Bot deployed to both your Test and Production environments, and there is only a single KB, shared by both environments.

You could use the [metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/quickstarts/add-question-metadata-portal#add-metadata-to-filter-the-answers) functionality provided QnA Maker to hold the common sub-path element of the URL (assuming that the document store directory structure is the same in both environments.)

e.g. data-path: documents/my-folder/my-subfolder/documents/word-document.doc

Then in .NET you could read in an environment variable which has the domain/unique bits of the path

e.g. https://mySiteTest.com/home

You'd then join the environment variable value and the meta-data value to get the full path.

e.g. https://mySiteTest.com/home/documents/my-folder/my-subfolder/documents/word-document.doc

To populate the environment variable in Azure you'd have to add it to the [App Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#add-or-edit) section of your bot's App Settings resource.

Obviously this is not a super scalable and introduces a maintenance cost going forward but it could solve your issue if the assumptions I've made about your setup are correct.